# React Router: How to navigate to another component using anchor tags

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am creating a [React App](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-bartik-k49bb) that displays recipes and in my `Recipe` component I want to be able to click on the anchor tags and navigate to another component called `RecipeInfo.js` and pass in some of the props along with it like `{title, ingredients}`. How exactly is this supposed to be set up? So far I have my `Recipe` component code like this

```
import React from "react";
export default function Recipe({ title, calories, image }) {
  return (
    <>
      <a href="/"><h1>{title}</h1></a>
      <p>{Math.round(calories)} calories</p>
      <img src={image} alt="" />
    </>
  );
}
```

and my App.js code like this

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import Recipe from "./Recipe.js";
import RecipeInfo from "./RecipeInfo.js";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const API_ID = "c38daf94";
  const API_KEY = "850d468a3e994692691631c7c259406c";

  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [query, setQuery] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getRecipes() {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=${API_ID}&app_key=${API_KEY}`
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      setRecipes(data.hits);
      console.log(data.hits);
    }
    if (query !== "") getRecipes();
  }, [query]);


  const updateRecipes = e => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };

  const getSearch = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(query)
    setQuery(search);
  };

  return (


    <div className="App">
      <input
        className="input"
        onChange={updateRecipes}
        value={search}
        type="text"
      />
      <button className="search" onClick={getSearch}>
        Search
      </button>
      <div className="recipes">
        {recipes.map(recipe => (
          <Recipe
            key={recipe.recipe.uri}
            title={recipe.recipe.label}
            calories={recipe.recipe.calories}
            image={recipe.recipe.image}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <Router>
        <Route
        exact path = "/recipeinfo"
        render={props => (
          <RecipeInfo
          {...props}

          />
        )}
        />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
```

and then replace `<a>` with `<Link to='/'>`

Answer (score 2):

In your first snippet you change your `a` tag with a `Link` component exported by react-router.

You can look at this example from the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/custom-link) for an example of custom `Link` integration. This component is useful because it will make call to the history API instead of just trying to load the url into the page.

Comment: I updated my Recipe component to ` <div className="recipe-card">
      <Router>
        <Link to="/recipeinfo">
          <h1>{title}</h1>
        </Link>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/recipeinfo">
            <RecipeInfo />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>` which links to the Recipe component whenever I click on the links. Now how do I pass in the props? I want it to display the recipe title and calories for 1 specific recipe whenever I click on a link

Comment: Couple of ways but this is another problem. From your snippet you could have a route like /recipe/:id/recipeinfo. You will be able to get the recipe id when the route is matched and load the appropriate data.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing a tag with Link component should work. I noticed some more issues in the code:

- there was a key provided in Recipe component, however the component itself was making no use of it, so it was pointless. Replaced fragment with div and provided the key there
- Trying to render the object {ingredients} as is would not work, since objects cannot be rendered by react. Replaced with a map, rendering ingredient.text
- Added the render method to Route exact path="/recipeinfo" like this, to acess ingredients inside the RecipeInfo component:

  `<Route exact path="/recipeinfo" render={() => (<RecipeInfo title={title}  ingredients={ingredients}/>)}/>`

Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-lucy-rtndk3)